# Save Pandas Dataframe Object inside Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataset and I was wondering if I can include it into a dictionary to export it as pickle together with other stuff.

i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
dict_ = {"other_stuff": "blabla", "pandas": df}
```

`pickle.dump(dict, "shared.pkl")`

When I open it, using:

```
fp = open("shared.pkl",'rb')
shared = pickle.load(fp)
df= shared["pandas"]
```

the pandas datframe is empty. Any idea if this is even possible or how to do it ?

EDIT:
I know that I can simply pickle the pandas object itself `df.to_pickle("shared.pkl")`, but I am interested in saving the other stuff together with the pandas document in one convenient pickle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the dict with

```
with open('shared.pkl', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(dict, f)
```

and then open it with

```
with open('shared.pkl', 'rb') as f:
   dict_ = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was wondering, if I can do it together with the other stuff inside a dictionary ?

Comment: @henry no problem, done :) When reading, I've changed your variable name from `dict` to `dict_`, as it's better to not use `dict` as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

The pickle.dump command expects a file object, not the name of the file.

```
from io import BytesIO
outfile = BytesIO()    
pickle.dump(dict_, outfile)    
outfile.seek(0)
unpickled_dict = pickle.read(outfile)
unpickled_dict['pandas'].info()
```

will give you the expected output.  The dataframe with plain datatypes should pickle just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain what BytesIO does and why you had to include it ?

Comment: BytesIO just gives you the binary file interface without writing to a disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can save it into a list or in a dict and then pickle it like normal.

And don't use built-in name like dict or list as name. Bad style and lead to unexpected events.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
data = {"other_stuff": "blabla", "pandas": df}


file_write = open(b"resources/shared.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(data, file_write)
file_write.close()

file_read = open(b"resources/shared.pkl","rb")
shared = pickle.load(file_read)
file_read.close()

print(shared["other_stuff"])
print(shared["pandas"])
```

## Output

```
blabla
  first_name last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason    Miller   42             4             25
1      Molly  Jacobson   52            24             94
2       Tina       Ali   36            31             57
3       Jake    Milner   24             2             62
4        Amy     Cooze   73             3             70
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So you are pickling a list, instead of a dictionary. Why do you chose to do so, instead of putting it into a dictionary ?

Comment: I need to be able to access the information using keys

Comment: true... you can also pickle other_data right away. Sometimes you miss the forest for the trees